# Distribution of random variables given their sum

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\theta>0$ and $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid with pdf $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{\theta}}.$$ Let $T(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n\vert X_i\vert.$ What is the distribution of $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ given $T=t$?

I have already calculated the pdf and distribution of $T$ and of $\vert X_i\vert$. Getting the joint pdf for $X$ is also straight forward. But how do i get this distribution?

Comment: May I ask in what connection does this problem arise?

Answer (score 0):

The $|X_i|$ are i.i.d. exponential, so their joint pdf is (as wlog $\theta=1$) simply $e^{-\sum X_i}$ which you are fixing. So the conditional joint density is uniform.